# Encrypt Configuration

Tags: c#, configuration

The code on the Site [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186234/Encrypt-Net-Configuration-file) (shown below) encrypts app.config. I ran this on a button press to encrypt my config.

When am i supposed to run the code - (e.g at application start-up in case it is not already encrypted)?
In my bin folder i have 2 xml configuration files (Applicationname.exe.config and Applicationname.vshost.exe - this code only encrypts the first one of them - When i deploy my program how do i ensure that the my customer doesn't accidentally get the unencrypted file also as this would be a major issue ?(Or does the windows installer take care of ensuring this)?

**C# Code**

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

SectionInformation appSettingsSecInfo = config.GetSection(
   "appSettings").SectionInformation;
if (!appSettingsSecInfo.IsProtected)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The configuration file has NOT been protected!");

    // Encrypt this section by using security provider 
    // (RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider or DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider).
    appSettingsSecInfo.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
    appSettingsSecInfo.ForceSave = true;

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
}
```

Comment: I believe I am correct in saying that you need to run this as you install the application, as the encryption utilised is machine-specific.  Encrypting this on your PC would result in a config file that cannot be read on another PC.

Comment: sounds like it might break etc with that method - i will go back and see if there is an easier way. I cant risk leaving passwords open. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow steps at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx). Author of the code snippet that you reference also does mention this page. But he is wrong about it not working on app.config files. All you have to do is rename yourapp.exe.config file to web.config, encrypt the sections you want and rename back to yourapp.exe.config.

Now to your scenario. The page that I have referenced also states the following:

> You can easily export and import RSA keys from server to server. This makes RSA encryption particularly effective for encrypting configuration files used on multiple servers in a Web farm.

And it has a section about exporting and importing RSA keys.

So you could encrypt the configuration on your PC, export RSA key used for encryption and put it in your installer. The installer would then import the RSA encryption key into machine or user store on PC on which the application is being deployed.

But you should realize that when the application is starting, encrypted configuration has to be decrypted using private part of RSA encryption key (that we imported or it originated on the PC). Therefore if the application can get access to the private key so might the customer (I presume that the customer has physical access to the PC with your application). What you could do is use a user key container of user that only the application will run under for RSA encryption key but if the customer has administrator rights you will not be able to forbid him from decrypting the configuration.

So much for standard solutions. But you can always put sensitive data in a custom xml file, encrypt it and the encryption key compile into you application. Then the application would have to implement a logic to decrypt the xml itself. The customer would have to decompile your application to get to the RSA encryption key.